# How to make pdf or docx file corrupted?

Tags: pdf, docx, corrupt

I am trying to get docx or pdf file corrupted so that it does not open at all. I am running ubuntu, so is there any way I can take pre-existing file and turn it to a corrupted file that can not be opened? I have done quite a bit of a research and it did not work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no real point, but just for personal knowledge, I would like to see if it can be done intentionally.

Comment: Not sure if this will work on Ubuntu, but on Windows I managed to open it as raw text, then just delete a few random characters and it stopped working

Comment: Yes, it can be done in various ways, but the question is what your goal is. Is it just so that common Word and PDF applications cannot open it? However, some corruption can be fixed by some other tools. Should the process be reversible, you'll want to uncorrupt it at some point? Why don't you encrypt DOCX and PDF files? Those formats have decent encryption features.